# Select and remove lines matching a pattern from a file

Tags: text-processing

```
grep -Eri "drucken" app/views

app/views/meths/_form.html.erb:                                <li class="hidden-phone"><a onclick="javascript: print();" class="">Methode drucken</a></li>
app/views/clients/show.html.erb:                    <li><a onclick="javascript: print();" class="" value="drucken">drucken</a></li>
app/views/clients/index.mobile.html.erb:                                <li class="hidden-xs"><a onclick="javascript: print();" class="">KlientInnen drucken</a></li>
app/views/treatments/index.html.erb:                        <li><a onclick="javascript: print();" class="" value="drucken">drucken</a></li>
```

I'm looking for a solution where I could do something like:

```
grep -Eri "drucken" app/views | xargs INTO_A_FANCY_TOOL_WHICH_REMOVES_THOSES LINES
```

**update:**

I want to remove those lines from the file.

Comment: `sed` should do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
grep -Eri -l "drucken" app/views | xargs sed -e '/drucken/d' -i
```

where '-l' tells grep to only print the file name, '-i' tells sed to modify that file on the fly.

Alternatively you could loop with sed over all files, but it will "touch" all of them even if the file doesn't contain the requested word:

```
find app/views -type f -exec sed -e '/drucken/d' -i {} \;
```

Comment: As other users said, you can of course use `grep -v`, but you'd need a loop like (assuming you have all files in the same views folder, use a find otherwise):  
`for f in app/views/*; do grep -v "drucken" $f > $f.new ; mv $f.new $f; done`

Comment: Do it by ONE prog `sed -ie '/drucken/d' app/views/*/*.html.erb`

Comment: @Costas sed -i <list of files>  will "touch" all your files even if they do not contain the unwanted term (so will do my other proposal above). If that is not important, then yes a single sed should do.

Comment: @Costas sed will not recursively search files in a folder tree, so all the files to modify must be therefore listed in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're looking for `grep -v`?

> ```
>   -v, --invert-match
>          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
>          is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

So `grep -v 'drucken' file1 > file2` will give you a `file2` with those lines removed.

Alternatively and untried, something along the lines of

```
sed -e '/drucken/d' infile > outfile
```

Comment: But I'd like to remove those lines from the file.

Comment: @auL5agoi: That's what grep -v does, apart from not having a n "in place" switch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a perl oneliner for that:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
$ perl -i -wne 'if(/b/){print STDOUT $_}else{print}' file
b
$ cat file
a
c
```